# IIS7 integrated mode closing token between requests

Tags: security, authentication, iis-7, authorization, objectdisposedexception

We are migrating to IIS7 integrated mode and have come across an issue. We authenticate using WindowsAuthentication but then store a reference to the WindowsPrincipal so that on future requests we can authorize as needed against AD. In IIS 7 Integrated mode, the token is being closed (between requests) so that when we try to run IsInRole it generates a disposed exception. Is there a way to cache this token or change our use of WindowsPrincipal so that we don't need to make successive AD requests to get it for each authorization request?

Here is the exception being thrown from WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole("")
- System.ObjectDisposedException: {"Safe handle has been closed"}

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried letting IIS cache the auth information for you?

Check out the options for the  section of web.config.  Specifically the `authPersistNonNTLM` and `authPersistSingleRequest` attributes.  PersistNonNTLM=True may do exactly what you need w/o any custom implementation in your code.

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication

Comment: This didn't solve our problem, but is good to know as we rebuild our security layer. It turns out that custom ISAPI/impersonation logic in our shop was causing the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `AcquireRequestState` event handler I just touched the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` as below

```
var t = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
var p = HttpContext.Current.Profile;
```

and in my WCF services I could use the `Identity` and the `Profile`, without a `ObjectDisposedException`.

I don't know why.